# OpenVAS always reporting no results

Tags: openvas

I've setup openvas on ubuntu and it appears to be working, however every scan I attempt returns 0 results.

I used `openvas-check-setup` to verify everything and it came back OK.  Any ideas on what could cause this? I'm running from the security assistant and checking some public IPs.

Thank you

Comment: dzm did you solve your problem?

Comment: Btw. similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081618/greenbone-community-edition-gce-does-not-give-results i think this is off-topic for stackoverflow.com (because it isn't about programming) but the flag of the first topic wasn't noticed so far.

Answer (score 3):

Some common issues if scans doesn't return any results:

1. You don't have nmap installed or not available within your PATH
2. The targets are not answering to an ICMP Echo Request
   -> Check the "Alive Test" setting of your Target definition and try some of the other available methods
3. SELinux is enabled and blocking the scanner from doing its job
4. You're using a custom scan configuration which doesn't include the "nmap (NASL wrapper)" and "Ping Host" NVTs from the "Port scanners" family

Only points 2. and 4. of the above are valid for the Greenbone VM (GCE). All prerequisites like nmap are already available / installed and SELinux isn't installed / enabled.

The mentioned "Ping Host" plugin allows to configure a "Report about unrechable Hosts" to "yes" so you will get at least some notes if a remote host is considered as dead. In that case you will get no results.

Disclaimer: Answer of a NVT Dev @ Greenbone

Comment: I am running OpenVAS in one VM on a Windows server 2016 machine, and trying to scan another one on the same server.  Getting nowhere either. I am using 'Consider Alive' as the test, I have tried using the IP or the server name as the address, can't get any results either.  One thing I can't figure out is whether the Greenbone VM includes nmap or not?  And should I worry about that?

Comment: Only points 2. and 4. of the above are valid for the Greenbone VM. All prerequisites like nmap are already available / installed and SELinux isn't installed / enabled. Your problem sound either like a networking issues (the target system isn't reachable at all) or you feed wasn't fully synced yet (the initial setup/sync can take up to hone our or more).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it seemed like nmap would have to be included but that wasn't specified anywhere.  The target system is my test VM, which is  reacheable from my entire domain, and resides on the same physical server as the OpenVAS VM, so I have a hard time figuring out why they wouldn't see each other.  And my feed was fully synched days before (according to its status).  That sort of leaves me high and dry :-)..

Comment: I would suggest to move further steps / discussions over to https://community.greenbone.net/ where your issues could be discussed in more detail. Especially as stackoverflow (which is about programming) is a quite wrong place for such topics.