# Greenbone Community Edition (GCE) does not give results

Tags: openvas

I have installed the Greenbone Community Edition (GCE) ISO mentioned at [installation](https://www.greenbone.net/en/install_use_gce/) in a virtual box in a Mint Linux with a bridged Adapter over WIFI in a home network. The IP that the virtual box got was 192.168.1.111.

Via advanced task wizard I started a new scan and after some sec it gave me the results:

[image: Results]

Actually it didn't give any results.

What am I doing wrong? Should I do something further?

Comment: duplicate of this fairly recent question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552189/openvas-always-reporting-no-results

Comment: Not necessarily, the Greenbone VM is different from a source installation (used in the linked question) in various points.

Comment: Btw. i still think this is off-topic for stackoverflow.com (because it isn't about programming) but the flag of the first topic wasn't noticed so far.

Answer (score 3):

The most common reason for this is that the target is not answering to an ICMP Echo Request which is the default method for deciding if a target is alive.

Please check the "Alive Test" setting of your Target definition (found via Configuration -> Targets) and try some of the other available methods like "TCP Service Ping" or even "Consider Alive".

One additional issue might originate from the initial sync of the NVT feed which could take up to one our or more. Without a fully synced feed (check the availability of the NVTs via SecInfo->NVTs) you also won't get any results.

Comment: should the remote server and openvas be in the same network? I thought that since I give ssh credentials it connects to the remote server and does the work from there? It doesn't work like that?

Comment: If I want to make penetration test to a server with public ip e.g. 51.1.10.1 I can't use openVAS?

Comment: The 192.168.1.111 is in a private network and 10.10.1.10 is the public ip of my remote server, which I can ping...shouldn't that work?

Comment: 10.10.1.10 is a private network and no remote server should have such a public IP address assigned.

Comment: It was an example...the public ip was 51.X.X.X